# I can't get object's id

Tags: javascript, json, object

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWaKX.png)

result of

```
function(a) {
    console.log(a.type + "/" + a.id);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

why I can't get a.id?

how do can I return a.id

Comment: you mean a.profile.id maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object passed to your method does not posses an ID property. This is the reason why it is failing. However, you can check the element that invoked the method and inspect why is there no ID on the provided object.

However, it has a property named "Profile" that contains a property named ID. If this is what you are looking for then the code below would help you solve your problem.

```
  console.log(a.profile.type + "/" + a.profile.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any id in the object. Id is in profile object. If you want to access profile id the you can use:

```
a.profile.id
a.profile['id']
```

else you have to include id in your primary object instead of profile.

Answer (score -2):

you can get your with

```
id = a.profile['id']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.